# Implementing Iterable with a nested class in Java

Tags: java, generics, iterator

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ItemList implements Iterable<Entry> {
    private List<Entry> entries;

    public static class Entry {
        private final String id;
        private int quantity;
    }

    @Overide public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
        return entries.iterator();
    }
}
```

This code will not compile.  (It claims it cannot find the "Entry" type in the ItemList class definition).

I want other classes to be able to iterate over the internal entries of this List.  I would rather not move the Entry class to a separate file, as that would require exposing many of the inner workings of that class to all of the other classes in the package.

My question is then: Why won't this compile?  And, what is the best way around this problem?

Comment: How might `ItemList` be used?

Comment: Try making the class `Entry` static.

Comment: This structure intuitively does not make sense. You are implementing `Iterable` of a private type. How can external classes use your `ItemList` without knowledge of `Entry`?

Comment: Now, I'm use to c# as opposed to java, but it seems to me that `ItemList` cannot truly implement `Iterable<Entry>` so long as `Entry` is private.  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SamIam ItemList is just a wrapper around the List.  Basically, I want to prevent other classes from using some of the List functionality.

Comment: @Tudor , etc.  Sorry I mistyped that.  It is actually a public static type.  I have no problems with making the type public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is scoping. Since `Entry` is an inner class it needs to be prefixed by the name of the "parent". Try this:

```
class ItemList implements Iterable<ItemList.Entry> {

    private List<Entry> entries;

    public static class Entry {
        private final String id = null;
        private int quantity;     
    }

    @Override public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
        return entries.iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.  I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Entry is a private class so other classes won't be able to see it. you can make it public but still keep it nested.

It should also be static since it doesn't depend on any state of the outer class.

Comment: Even with the Entry public static, you still get the compile error.

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance, but `Entry` appears to be intended to be an instanceable class.  are `static` classes instanceable in java?

Comment: Sure, a static class just means that it doesn't require an instance of the outer class.

Comment: See @Tudors answer. It is correct. I missed the fact that the generic parameter did not include the outer class name.